# Finding highest value and lowercase/capitals in do-while loops

Tags: java

I have to write a program that asks the user to enter an integer value. After each value, the user has to respond with a "y" or a "n" if he/she wants to continue with the program, and each number the user enters is stated as either odd or even and find the averages of the numbers that the user entered. I have completed all this, but I am confused on two things:

1. How do I make it so that the user can type in both a capital and lowercase y and the program will still run? So far, it only works with a lowercase y.
2. Also, how would you program it so that it would give you the highest number the user inputted after the user is done putting in all the numbers? 
   Ex: user puts in numbers 10,12,13, and the program states "The highest value entered was 13."

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ProgramTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String answer = "";
        double sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        do {

            int num;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter any number : ");
            num = scan.nextInt();

            if ((num % 2) == 0) System.out.println(num + " is an even number.");
            else System.out.println(num + " is an odd number");
            sum += num;
            System.out.println(("Would you like to enter another value(y/n)?:"));
            answer = scan.next();
            count++;

        } while (answer.equals("y"));

        System.out.println("Average: " + (sum/count));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get case insensitive comparison try

```
while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase ("y"));
```

For the highest and lowest create two new variables before the `do` loop as

```
int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

In your loop do

```
lowest = Math.min (lowest, num);
highest = Math.min (higest, num);
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at `String.equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString)` in Java documentation for lower and uppercase `y`.

As for the highest/lowest number, create 2 variables and if they are null or lower/higher than current number, reassign them. By the end of the program, you will have appropriate value.

This is too simple to provide you the code, so, the explanation above is enough so far.

Comment: Thank you for the lower and uppercase, but I don't understand what you mean by the variables. Where will I put the variables, and how do i reassign them to another number if one number is greater than the other?

Comment: Forgive me if it seems really basic to you, this is my first year doing Java and computer programming in general, I'm still getting used to it. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ProgramTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String answer = "";
    double sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    **int max = 0;**
    do {

        int num;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter any number : ");

        num = scan.nextInt();

        if ((num % 2) == 0) System.out.println(num + " is an even number.");
        else System.out.println(num + " is an odd number");
        sum += num;
        System.out.println(("Would you like to enter another value(y/n)?:"));

        **max = (num > max) ? num : max ;** 

        answer = scan.next();
        count++;

    } while (answer.equals("y"));

      System.out.println("Average: " + (sum/count));
      System.out.println("Highest : " + max);   
  }
```